# Integrate Power BI tiles to my web app

Tags: iframe, embed, azure-active-directory, powerbi

According to the article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt450498.aspx I am able to integrate tiles to my web applications. I am planning to create separate tiles for each user (not Power BI user) in my system using my Power BI account and embed each tile which belongs to the user on their pages using the technique described at the link. I have no problem about data refresh rates for free user (daily). My question is do I need to have a Power BI user account (free or pro) for each user on my site or can I use them anonymously from Power BI server (impersonation) perspective by scripting like generating access tokens for related tile according to current site user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have registered your application in Azure Active Directory, the API have to authenticate the Power BI user in order to access to user tiles.

> All of the Power BI APIs mentioned below require an application
>   registered in AAD. Your application needs to login a Power BI user and
>   make the API calls to access the user’s account.

[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbidev/archive/2015/09/23/power-bi-api-updates-roundup.aspx)